# JSoup getting rid of line breaks in body

Tags: java, scala, jsoup

Is there anyway preserve line breaks in plain-text pages using JSoup? I am trying to pull a [robots.txt](https://www.facebook.com/robots.txt) and instead of it coming through line by line, it is pulling the whole body tag in one line.

```
var response = Jsoup.connect("http://www.facebook.com/robots.txt").userAgent(userAgent).followRedirects(true).execute()
println(response.parse().body().text())
```

I get the text response on a single line like so:

```
# Notice: Crawling Facebook is prohibited unless you have express written # permission. See: http://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php User-agent: Applebot Disallow: /ajax/ Disallow: /album.php Disallow: /checkpoint/ Disallow: /contact_importer/ Disallow: /feeds/ Disallow: /file_download.php Disallow: /hashtag/ Disallow: /l.php Disallow: /live/ Disallow: /moments_app/ Disallow: /p.php Disallow: /photo.php Disallow: /photos.php Disallow: /sharer/ User-agent: baiduspider Disallow: /ajax/ Disallow: /album.php Disallow: /checkpoint/ Disallow: /contact_importer/ Disallow: /feeds/ Disallow: /file_download.php Disallow: /hashtag/ Disallow: /l.php Disallow: /live/ Disallow: /moments_app/ Disallow: /p.php Disallow: /photo.php Disallow: /photos.php Disallow: /sharer/ User-agent: Bingbot Disallow: /ajax/ Disallow: /album.php Disallow: /checkpoint/ Disallow: /contact_importer/ Disallow: /feeds/ Disallow: /file_download.php Disallow: /hashtag/ Disallow: /l.php Disallow: /live/ Disallow: /moments_app/ Disallow: /p.php Disallow: /photo.php Disallow: /photos.php Disallow: /sharer/ User-agent: Googlebot Disallow: /ajax/ Disallow: /album.php Disallow: /checkpoint/ Disallow: /contact_importer/ Disallow: /feeds/ Disallow: /file_download.php Disallow: /hashtag/ Disallow: /l.php Disallow: /live/ Disallow: /moments_app/ Disallow: /p.php Disallow: /photo.php Disallow: /photos.php Disallow: /sharer/ User-agent: ia_archiver Disallow: / Disallow: /ajax/ Disallow: /album.php Disallow: /checkpoint/ Disallow: /contact_importer/ Disallow: /feeds/ Disallow: /file_download.php Disallow: /hashtag/ Disallow: /l.php Disallow: /live/ Disallow: /moments_app/ Disallow: /p.php Disallow: /photo.php Disallow: /photos.php Disallow: /sharer/ User-agent: msnbot Disallow: /ajax/ Disallow: /album.php Disallow: /checkpoint/ Disallow: /contact_importer/ Disallow: /feeds/ Disallow: /file_download.php Disallow: /hashtag/ Disallow: /l.php Disallow: /live/ Disallow: /moments_app/ Disallow: /p.php Disallow: /photo.php Disallow: /photos.php Disallow: /sharer/ User-agent: Naverbot Disallow: /ajax/ Disallow: /album.php Disallow: /checkpoint/ Disallow: /contact_importer/ Disallow: /feeds/ Disallow: /file_download.php Disallow: /hashtag/ Disallow: /l.php Disallow: /live/ Disallow: /moments_app/ Disallow: /p.php Disallow: /photo.php Disallow: /photos.php Disallow: /sharer/ User-agent: seznambot Disallow: /ajax/ Disallow: /album.php Disallow: /checkpoint/ Disallow: /contact_importer/ Disallow: /feeds/ Disallow: /file_download.php Disallow: /hashtag/ Disallow: /l.php Disallow: /live/ Disallow: /moments_app/ Disallow: /p.php Disallow: /photo.php Disallow: /photos.php Disallow: /sharer/ User-agent: Slurp Disallow: /ajax/ Disallow: /album.php Disallow: /checkpoint/ Disallow: /contact_importer/ Disallow: /feeds/ Disallow: /file_download.php Disallow: /hashtag/ Disallow: /l.php Disallow: /live/ Disallow: /moments_app/ Disallow: /p.php Disallow: /photo.php Disallow: /photos.php Disallow: /sharer/ User-agent: teoma Disallow: /ajax/ Disallow: /album.php Disallow: /checkpoint/ Disallow: /contact_importer/ Disallow: /feeds/ Disallow: /file_download.php Disallow: /hashtag/ Disallow: /l.php Disallow: /live/ Disallow: /moments_app/ Disallow: /p.php Disallow: /photo.php Disallow: /photos.php Disallow: /sharer/ User-agent: Twitterbot Disallow: /ajax/ Disallow: /album.php Disallow: /checkpoint/ Disallow: /contact_importer/ Disallow: /feeds/ Disallow: /file_download.php Disallow: /hashtag/ Disallow: /l.php Disallow: /live/ Disallow: /moments_app/ Disallow: /p.php Disallow: /photo.php Disallow: /photos.php Disallow: /sharer/ User-agent: Yandex Disallow: /ajax/ Disallow: /album.php Disallow: /checkpoint/ Disallow: /contact_importer/ Disallow: /feeds/ Disallow: /file_download.php Disallow: /hashtag/ Disallow: /l.php Disallow: /live/ Disallow: /moments_app/ Disallow: /p.php Disallow: /photo.php Disallow: /photos.php Disallow: /sharer/ User-agent: Yeti Disallow: /ajax/ Disallow: /album.php Disallow: /checkpoint/ Disallow: /contact_importer/ Disallow: /feeds/ Disallow: /file_download.php Disallow: /hashtag/ Disallow: /l.php Disallow: /live/ Disallow: /moments_app/ Disallow: /p.php Disallow: /photo.php Disallow: /photos.php Disallow: /sharer/ User-agent: Applebot Allow: /ajax/pagelet/generic.php/PagePostsSectionPagelet Allow: /safetycheck/ User-agent: baiduspider Allow: /ajax/pagelet/generic.php/PagePostsSectionPagelet Allow: /safetycheck/ User-agent: Bingbot Allow: /ajax/pagelet/generic.php/PagePostsSectionPagelet Allow: /safetycheck/ User-agent: Googlebot Allow: /ajax/pagelet/generic.php/PagePostsSectionPagelet Allow: /safetycheck/ User-agent: ia_archiver Allow: /about/privacy Allow: /ajax/pagelet/generic.php/PagePostsSectionPagelet Allow: /full_data_use_policy Allow: /legal/terms Allow: /policy.php Allow: /safetycheck/ User-agent: msnbot Allow: /ajax/pagelet/generic.php/PagePostsSectionPagelet Allow: /safetycheck/ User-agent: Naverbot Allow: /ajax/pagelet/generic.php/PagePostsSectionPagelet Allow: /safetycheck/ User-agent: seznambot Allow: /ajax/pagelet/generic.php/PagePostsSectionPagelet Allow: /safetycheck/ User-agent: Slurp Allow: /ajax/pagelet/generic.php/PagePostsSectionPagelet Allow: /safetycheck/ User-agent: teoma Allow: /ajax/pagelet/generic.php/PagePostsSectionPagelet Allow: /safetycheck/ User-agent: Twitterbot Allow: /ajax/pagelet/generic.php/PagePostsSectionPagelet Allow: /safetycheck/ User-agent: Yandex Allow: /ajax/pagelet/generic.php/PagePostsSectionPagelet Allow: /safetycheck/ User-agent: Yeti Allow: /ajax/pagelet/generic.php/PagePostsSectionPagelet Allow: /safetycheck/ User-agent: * Disallow: / ]
```

I'm looking to parse the file line by line(like viewing it in a browser, and performing a regex on it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unflattened text is available via a TextNode in Jsoup.  E.g.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.facebook.com/robots.txt").get();
doc.body().textNodes().get(0).getWholeText()
```

Answer (score 1):

How about doing it a little differently and pulling the file instead. `robots.txt` is obviously a text file so we can scrape that instead of attempt to scrape the HTML.

This is still using Jsoup, just a little differently than before.

```
Connection.Response robotsText = Jsoup.connect( "https://www.facebook.com/robots.txt" ).execute();
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = ( new FileOutputStream( new File( "robots.txt" ) ) );
fileOutputStream.write( robotsText.bodyAsBytes() );
fileOutputStream.close();
```

Comment: This will likely work, but the function is part of a bigger program that will also  need to parse normal html pages, df778899's is a better solution in my case.